# Dynamically adding multiple Images to a Crystal Report in vb.net (WinForms)

Tags: vb.net, winforms, crystal-reports

Looking for some assistance.

I have previously added a single image to a Crystal Report using a DataSet and a subform.

I thought that I would be able to replicate this for multiple images.

I have created the Dataset 'Images' with 8 rows named img1 -> img8

I have created a Subreport based on that dataset.

In my vb code I set the datasource of the SubReport as follows:

Initial Call:

```
    alertReport.OpenSubreport("AlertImages").SetDataSource(CreateImages(alertID))
```

Create Images:

```
Private Function CreateImages(ByVal alertID As Integer) As DataSet

        Dim data As New DataSet()

        data.Locale = Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
        data.Tables.Add("Images")
        data.Tables(0).Columns.Add("img", System.Type.GetType("System.Byte[]"))

        Try

            Dim path As String = String.Format("{0}\{1}", HighAlertPath, alertID.ToString())

            If (Directory.Exists(path)) Then

                Dim cnt As Integer = 1

                For Each fi As FileInfo In New DirectoryInfo(path).GetFiles

                    If (cnt <= 8) Then

                        If (fi.Extension = ".jpg" Or fi.Extension = ".png" Or fi.Extension = ".bmp") Then

                            Dim row As DataRow = GetImageRow(data.Tables(0), fi.FullName)
                            data.Tables(0).Rows.Add(row)
                            cnt += 1

                        End If

                    End If
                Next

            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try

        Return data

    End Function
```

Get Image Row:

```
Private Function GetImageRow(ByVal tbl As DataTable, ByVal fileName As String) As DataRow

    Using fs As New FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open)
        Using br As New BinaryReader(fs)

            Dim row As DataRow = tbl.NewRow()
            row(0) = br.ReadBytes(CInt(br.BaseStream.Length))

            Return row

        End Using
    End Using

End Function
```

I can confirm that the file location does have images in, and they are added to the datatable, but for some reason they do not show in the sub report.

do I need to name the rows as they are added to the datatable, since my subreport expects fields img1 -> img8

Comment: Can anyone shed any light on this one for me?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you create a PictureObject in runtime, add the picture on it and then add it to the report.

Take a look at this code:

```
Dim crxReport as CRAXDRT.Report
Dim objOLE As CRAXDRT.OLEObject
Dim objPic As StdPicture

'set all your CRAXDRT report and application objects, recordsets, etc

Set objPic = LoadPicture("myPath\myPic.bmp")

'here I am adding a picture object to the first section of the report
'now spacing here might get weird, you need to play with this and 
'figure out where this object will go

Set objOLE =   crxReport.Sections(1).AddPictureObject("myPath\myPic.bmp",0, 0)

'Set attributes of the image, we are dynamically creating it
'again you need to adjust accordingly

With objOLE
    .Height = objPic.Height * 500 / 1000
    .Width = objPic.Width * 500/ 1000
    .Left = (crxReport.Sections(1).Width) - objPic.Width
End With

Set objOLE = Nothing
Set objPic = Nothing
```

http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/database-and-reporting/109005-inserting-picture-objects-run-time-crystal-report.html